# Manage downloaded contents in iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, sqlite, filesystems

I am writing an iPhone app which would download articles (UTF8 text files) from my server. The app is then supposed to produce a listing of the filenames. Upon clicking the filename, the file contents would be displayed. It is very similar to an email program or RSS reader.

My question is, what is the best way of saving / retrieving the content on the device? One option is to put it all into a sqlite db. The other option could be to download the contents and save it in a new file. Any other solutions?

Any advantages/disadvantages for these approaches?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For some rather small amount of data in a simple structure you could store it in an NSMutableDictionary and use its methods for writing the content to file and for reading from a file.

Your data structure seems to be simple enough for that. If the amount of data is small enough I cannot say. If your list may grow endless then you shoud go for sqlite or for core data rather than a simple dictionay. A dictionary will be stored completely in RAM. With sqlite ore core data you can utilize RAM more efficiently by loading not much more records as are curently displayed.